# How to overload operator new to implement a fast allocator for a class?

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, overloading, static-methods

1, I already have a fast allocator like this:

```
struct FastAllocator
{
    FastAllocator(size_t fixed_size);
    void* Allocate(size_t size);
    void  Free(void* ptr);
};
```

2, I also have a class A that is required to be dynamically allocated/deleted quickly. So I think of overloading `operator new` and `operator delete` inside class A's definition like this:

```
struct A
{
    int buf[1024];

    void* operator new(size_t size);
    void  operator delete(void* ptr);
};
```

3, Because `operator new` and `operator delete` are both static methods, thus, I cannot access the `this` pointer.

**4, My question is: How should I initialize the `FastAllocator`'s instance that can be accessed by `operator new` and `operator delete`?**

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper for `FastAllocator` that is type aware.

```
template <typename T>
class FastAllocatorByType {
    static FastAllocator & fa () {
        static FastAllocator fastalloc(sizeof(T));
        return fastalloc;
    }
public:
    static void* Allocate(size_t size) { return fa().Allocate(size); }
    static void  Free(void* ptr) { fa().Free(ptr); }
};
```

Then, the `new` and `delete` overloads can call into the wrapper.

```
struct A
{
    typedef FastAllocatorByType<A> FastAlloc;

    int buf[1024];

    void* operator new(size_t size) { return FastAlloc::Allocate(size); }
    void  operator delete(void* ptr) { FastAlloc::Free(ptr); }
};
```